# Write out relation from a function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I have this problem:
"Let $R$ be a binary relation $(x,y)\in R$ if and only if $f(x) = f(y)$

where $f: \{a, b, c, d\} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ given by $f(a) = 0$, $f(b) = 1$, $f(c) = 0$, $f(d) = 0$

Write out $R$ and show that it's an equivalence relation."

I can't seem to grasp this particular question. Particularly the part about $f(x) = f(y)$

I know that it has $R$ has to be reflexive, symmetric and transitive for it to be an equivalence relation, but I guess I'm having trouble seeing exactly what's in $R$. I know it's supposed to be a subset of $\{a, b, c, d\}\times\{0, 1\}$, but the restriction $f(x) = f(y)$ is confusing me. Wondered if someone could explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R = {(a,c), (c,a), (a,d), (d,a), (d,c), (c,d), (a,a), (c,c), (d,d), (b,b)}

Hope that helps.

Note: The claim that R should be a subset of {a,b,c,d}x{0,1} is incorrect.

Comment: Ok, thank you! But I don't really understand how you thought to get that relation

Comment: Just followed the definition by being super-literal. I don't know if this clarifies anything for you. One thing worth noting is that even though $f$ is a relation on {a,b,c,d}x{0,1} and it is used to define the relation R, that doesn't necessarily have to mean that the relation R is on the same Cartesian product. The question essentially asks for you to identify/define the "quotient space" under the function $f$: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuotientSpace.html. If you want to check that the answer is correct, just plug in each element to check that $f(x)=f(y)$ holds -- from that maybe you will

Comment: be able to see the intuition behind the result too. Really it was more of process of elimination than anything: for which elements y does f(a)=f(y)? c,d. For b? No other element. For c? a,d. For d? a,c. Oh wait if this is supposed to define an equivalence relation I need to have a tuple including b somehow. Oh yeah I guess f(b)=f(b) is true. And then that means I also need to include (a,a), (c,c), and (d,d) too. That was basically my line of "reasoning".